# Is it possible to chain route redirects in loaded modules? (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to be able to chain route redirect paths with unloaded modules in Angular so I can keep the path info in the relative module configuring the route paths.

e.g. In app-routes.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
  { path: 'feature',  loadChildren: 'app/feature/feature.module#FeatureModule' },
  //----- App Root Routing Necessary Safeguards (AppRoutingModule) ----------
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, /* '/home' only so I can change the relative route paths in home-routing.module without going back here */
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

e.g. In home-routes.module.ts.. It needs to also handle a redirect. (even from a previous redirect)

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home/start', pathMatch: 'full' }, /* Placed first since it's a first-match win in config */
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'start', component: startComponent },
        { path: 'component-two', component: ComponentTwo },
        { path: 'component-three', component: ComponentThree },
    ]
  },
];
```

I am able to get my redirect when I use the path `/home`, but not when it uses the default empty path `/`.

e.g. Redirect behavior on loading the app (urls at left and redirects at right):

- `/` ---> `/home`
- `/home` --> `/home/start`

Desired behavior:

- `/` ---> `/home/start`
- `/home` --> `/home/start`

What config should I use at home-routes.module to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved with redirectTo:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10120
(You can reopen the issue and show your case (maybe they'll add chaining redirects))

But there are some workarounds:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3600-chaining-absolute-and-local-redirects-with-the-router-in-angular-7-2-13.htm

I have realized now how old this question is.